# In which league would one have to be, just to be considered average (statistically)?

Tags: starcraft-2

There are different numbers of players in each Battle.net League. If we consider only active players, which league would be the average (skills wise)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the statistics of [sc2ranks.com](http://sc2ranks.com/stats/league/all/1/all), currently over 50% of all players are either in silver or bronze league. This means the median of skill is somewhere at the top of silver league.

Those statistics are only for the current ladder season, so inactive players aren't counted.

Answer (score 8):

From [Liquipedia's page on the Battle.net leagues](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Battle.net_Leagues#The_Leagues):

```
League        Targeted Ratio of *Active* Players
----------------------------------------------
Grandmaster   200 players
Master        2%
Diamond       18%
Platinum      20%
Gold          20%
Silver        20%
Bronze        20%
```

This means that the average (and median) player should be in the Gold league.